# Getting Table's Row Index Using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Need to retrieve an index of a row in LINQ, then use that value to specify my DropDownList.SelectedIndex upon page load or postback.

```
    public String GetRoleName(Int16 RoleID)
    {
        SQL_TA_SCOREBOARDEntities1 c = new SQL_TA_SCOREBOARDEntities1();

        String qry = (from b in c.EmployeeAccessLevels
                      where b.id == RoleID
                      select b.Role).FirstOrDefault();

        return qry;
    }
```

I take the name of the Role for the dropdownlist to display but it doesn't work anyway.

```
            String RoleName = MyClass.RoleName(RoleID);
            ddlRole.Text = RoleName
```

So 
I really need the index instead.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong. Use `ddl.SelectedItem` to set selected item, not the index.

Comment: I tried, doesn't work. :(

Comment: Use ddlRole.SelectedValue = RoleID instead

Comment: My id's are 1,2,5 and 6 so I can't do that. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think retrieving a row's index is directly possible in LINQ.

You could just try

```
    ddlRole.Items[0].Text = RoleName
```

Comment: sorry for bothering on such a simple question :(

Comment: It's ok we all start somewhere. :)